# SQL Hierarchy Query

Tags: sql, database, oracle11g

```
SELECT ppse.SUBORDINATE_POSITION_ID child_position_id
               ,ppse.PARENT_POSITION_ID manger_position_id
               ,b.person_id
FROM per_pos_structure_elements_v ppse
      ,APPS.xxkpc_hr_personnel_v2_mv  b
WHERE b.position_id(+) = ppse.SUBORDINATE_POSITION_ID

AND ppse.POS_STRUCTURE_VERSION_ID =64
AND ppse.PARENT_POSITION_ID=12493
```

Output for this Query :

```
12604   12493   400 
12605   12493   108 
13644   12493   37897   
12752   12493   18  
13643   12493       
13642   12493       
13641   12493       



SELECT ppse.SUBORDINATE_POSITION_ID child_position_id
               ,ppse.PARENT_POSITION_ID manger_position_id
               ,b.person_id
FROM per_pos_structure_elements_v ppse
              ,APPS.xxkpc_hr_personnel_v2_mv  b
WHERE b.position_id(+) = ppse.SUBORDINATE_POSITION_ID

AND ppse.POS_STRUCTURE_VERSION_ID =64
AND ppse.PARENT_POSITION_ID=12504


12514   12504   449
12483   12504   450
12487   12504   456
12497   12504   156
12889   12504   168
12493   12504
```

12493 is parent in first query and is child in 2nd query so I need remove all rows which have null person_id(Third Column) & not parent for child's as in 2nd query i cannot remove last row coz he is a parent for child's as in first query but to remove the last 3 rows in first query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this...

```
SELECT ppse.SUBORDINATE_POSITION_ID child_position_id
           ,ppse.PARENT_POSITION_ID manger_position_id
           ,b.person_id
FROM per_pos_structure_elements_v ppse
  ,APPS.xxkpc_hr_personnel_v2_mv  b
WHERE b.position_id(+) = ppse.SUBORDINATE_POSITION_ID
AND b.type(+) = 'KPC Employee'
AND ppse.POS_STRUCTURE_VERSION_ID =64
AND ppse.PARENT_POSITION_ID=12493
AND 
(b.person_id!=null OR 
 ppse.SUBORDINATE_POSITION_ID in
             (SELECT SUBORDINATE_POSITION_ID from per_pos_structure_elements_v))
```

Comment: it is not working with PARENT_POSITION_ID=12504 it remove the row for 12493 which is parent for child's

Comment: try removing the NOT from the last statement. Shown below...
ppse.SUBORDINATE_POSITION_ID in
             (SELECT SUBORDINATE_POSITION_ID from per_pos_structure_elements_v))